# How to control segments with SevSeg library

Tags: library, display

The [SevSeg](https://github.com/DeanIsMe/SevSeg) library by Dean Reading seems to have a keyword to control individual segments on SSD's. I am using four common cathode, single digit displays. Does anyone know how to program individual segments?

```
#include "SevSeg.h"; 

SevSeg sevseg; 

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:

  byte numDigits = 4;
  byte digitPins[] = {2, 3, 4, 5};
  byte segmentPins[] = {6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13};
  bool resistorsOnSegments = false; // 'false' means resistors are on digit pins
  byte hardwareConfig = COMMON_CATHODE; // See README.md for options
  bool updateWithDelays = false; // Default 'false' is Recommended
  bool leadingZeros = false; // Use 'true' if you'd like to keep the leading zeros
  bool disableDecPoint = false; // Use 'true' if your decimal point doesn't exist or isn't connected. Then, you only need to specify 7 segmentPins[]

  sevseg.begin(hardwareConfig, numDigits, digitPins, segmentPins, 
    resistorsOnSegments,
    updateWithDelays, leadingZeros, disableDecPoint);

}


void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

  sevseg.setSegments();
  //sevseg.setNumber(1234,0);
  //sevseg.setChars("");
  //sevseg.blank();
  sevseg.refreshDisplay();

}
```

Comment: why did you not put a parameter into the `setSegments()` function call?

Comment: Because i don't yet know what parameter to put, or how to use the function.

Comment: tried that. displays a bunch of gibberish.

Comment: It is always the same if you just enter 1, or 2, or 25 etc.. I don't think that's how the function works. Displaying numbers with the setNumber function works perfectly however, so my displays are wired correctly.

Comment: what is unclear here https://github.com/DeanIsMe/SevSeg/blob/9cdc6d03d820ffbc18174921fb7bd0a3d030fd8b/SevSeg.cpp#L435

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't with that library. The author has not provided any public methods that will do the job.

There are private methods (`segmentOn` and `segmentOff`) that might be usable, but you would have to modify the library to be able to access them.

Comment: Are 4 and 2 just arbitrary numbers you chose?

Comment: Yes. They are the segment number you want to turn on or off.

Comment: How would you specify which digit?

Comment: Probably with different numbers. Experiment and find out.

Comment: Last question.. Where should those functions be placed within the code? I'm getting "private within this context".

Comment: Actually, that looks like that might be the case. I have never used this library, so I was just reading the source code. It looks like the actual answer might be "You can't with that library". Damn.

Comment: The simple answer is probably to use a different library.

Comment: I wonder why he included the setSegment() function then. And yeah using a different library doesn't seem like a bad idea either.

Comment: He probably uses it internally.